# Get the mean of last 4 layers of deep neural network for a 3D PyTorch tensor object

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, neural-network, mean

I am trying to get the mean of last 4 layers of `BERT deep neural network.`

Every hidden layer is of dimension:

```
outputs[1][-1]=[2,256,768] where 2 is batch size 
outputs[1][-2]=[2,256,768] where 2 is batch size 
outputs[1][-3]=[2,256,768] where 2 is batch size 
outputs[1][-4]=[2,256,768] where 2 is batch size
```

I want to `mean` the 4 layers and output should be of same dimension `[2,256,768]`

Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, bert_model, num_labels):
        super(BERT_CRF, self).__init__()
        self.bert = bert_model
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(768, num_labels)
        self.crf = CRF(num_labels, batch_first = True)

def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask,  labels=None, token_type_ids=None):
    outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask) 
    sequence_output = torch.cat((outputs[1][-1], outputs[1][-2], outputs[1][-3], outputs[1][-4]),-1).mean(dim=[0,1,2])
    sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
    emission = self.classifier(sequence_output)
```

I try to do  `sequence_output = torch.cat((outputs[1][-1], outputs[1][-2], outputs[1][-3], outputs[1][-4]),-1).mean(dim=[0,1,2])`

But it does not give me the result as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to stack the four tensors and average the newly created dimensions. Since you are looking at the last four elements of `outputs[1]`, you can do:

```
>>> outputs[1,-4:].mean(0)
```

This would return the average of `outputs[1][-1]`, `outputs[1][-2]`, `outputs[1][-3]`, and `outputs[1][-4]`...